# CSS, height of <div> tags and scroll

Tags: css, html

I have CSS problems. I will try to explain my problem to you with using pictures.
I have a web page like this:
[image: This must be normal view]

This is the view that I don't want while it is full with words:
[image: Content view overflows from page but there is no scrolling in page]

But I don't want these ones. I want this: while content(content div) is full with words, It will expand to bottom and a scroll will appear right side of page. As a result, I want a content that expands without not effected top div but effects bottom div to move bottom together.

I hope I have explained my problem..

Comment: why dont you create a [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net) of this, it's to understand what you mean

Comment: I can't because I don't know what should I do, If I knew, I did :).
Normally, I used to use <table> with html. This is my first time using <div>s..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think this is what you want:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="top">This is the top div</div>
        <div id="main">This is the main div</div>
        <div id="bottom">This is the bottom div</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
}

#content{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 800px;
}

#top{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF0;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 800px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

#main{
    margin-top: 100px;  
}

#bottom{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FF0;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: No sir, It must expand but it didn't, you can see: http://jsfiddle.net/dmrc1143/yzDQS/

Comment: @dmrc1143 I don't think that's my code exactly, because I made it in jsfiddle in the first place: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/vYcEf/ Drag the slider all the way to the left so you can see the whole thing.

Comment: auw, yess..
Sir, can you add a div to right place of main div and it will expand with main div.(?)

Comment: @dmrc1143 I'm not sure if this is what you meant or not: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/vYcEf/1/

Comment: Yes, I want this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use overflow: auto in your CSS along with a fixed height to make a div show a scrollbar when the content within it gets too big, rather than expanding. Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, Yes I want a scroll but I want it for my page not for my div and It must appear auto namely without using overflow:auto. Like this page. You can see scroll right side of page.
And my div will expand but without scroll. Page will have scroll not my div. And my div will effect bottom div, move to bottom..